# I'm trying to write a code that gets the sum of all digits in a number but it isn't working

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java and currently doing practice and came across this question.

Write a program that generates one random number. The range of the random
number is 0 to 10000. Display the number and the sum of all the digits in the number

This is my code and I can't figure out why its not printing the sum. Please help!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random1 = new Random();
        int num = random1.nextInt(10000);
        System.out.println(num);

        while(num > 0) {

            int sum = 0;
            int last_digit = num % 10;
            sum  = sum + last_digit;
            num = num / 10;

        System.out.println(sum);

        }    

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Currently you redeclare `sum` as `0` in each iteration. Just put `int sum = 0;` outside of the loop. And put the printing after the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is that you are only declaring your sum variable inside your loop and initializing it to 0 in every iteration.

Initialize the sum variable before the loop and only print once your loop is done:

```
int sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {

    int last_digit = num % 10;
    sum = sum + last_digit;
    num = num / 10;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this a while ago but it gave me an error saying sum isn't initialized somehow. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition of `sum` outside the loop:

```java
int sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {
    sum += num % 10;  // add last digit to sum
    num = num / 10;   // remove last digit from input
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random random1 = new Random();
    int num = random1.nextInt(10000);
    System.out.println(num);

    int sum;
    for(sum = 0; num > 0; sum += num % 10, num /= 10);
    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).